# Accessing modified files in repository using JGit

Tags: git, jgit

I am using JGit to access a local repository using Java. I need to access the changed files of a repository which is typically executed using the `git status` command in git. What is the JGit implementation for this command?

So basically I need the JGit representation of a typical:

> git status

**My current implementation:**

```
private void initRepository(String path){
    try {
        File workTree = new File(path);
        Git git = Git.open(workTree);
        //I need to get all the modified/changed files here     
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        //handle exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of a `git status` command can be run as follows

```
Status status = git.status().call();
```

With the various bits of information then being retrieved from the status object:

```
System.out.println("Added: " + status.getAdded());
System.out.println("Changed: " + status.getChanged());
System.out.println("Conflicting: " + status.getConflicting());
System.out.println("ConflictingStageState: " + status.getConflictingStageState());
System.out.println("IgnoredNotInIndex: " + status.getIgnoredNotInIndex());
System.out.println("Missing: " + status.getMissing());
System.out.println("Modified: " + status.getModified());
System.out.println("Removed: " + status.getRemoved());
System.out.println("Untracked: " + status.getUntracked());
System.out.println("UntrackedFolders: " + status.getUntrackedFolders());
```

Source: [JGit Cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowStatus.java)